# Javascript pre-loader not waiting for images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this Javascript to activate my [website](http://horizonstudios.hol.es)'s pre-loader. However, it seems to disappears once the page has loaded and not when images have finished loading.

After searching I found someone suggesting window.onload which waits until images have loaded, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it into my existing Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function to hide your preloader, you can attach to the event in jQuery using the following snippet:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
}):
```

Make sure to use the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method signature and not the event signature [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.

You should note the following from the [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) docs:

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull (: